# Issue with HTTP link not forwarding to HTTPS

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect, ssl, https

I have recently implemented the HTTPS/SSL on a website. I have impleted it correctly and everything works correctly accept 1 issue.

When I got to www.domain.com or doamin.com directly it doesnt go to the https://www.domain.com instead it just stays on the non https link. How can this be fixed?

My site is on Wordpress and using W3TC Page Cache plugin

Answer (score 0):

In the `.htaccess` file in the root of your server, or in the Apache config add a rewrite rule to redirect HTTP to HTTPS:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
```

Test the rules on http://htaccess.madewithlove.be/.